# Converting output of ls -ltr to date format %m%d %H:%M

Tags: awk

i am writing a awk script for getting modification date and then converting them but getting a problem in converting output of `ls -lrt` to date format "month/date hour:date"

My awk script:-

```
awk 'BEGIN{
    "ls -lrt "ARGV[1] "| awk '{\"print $6$7$8\" +\"%Y%m/%d %H:%M\"}'" | getline cdatefile1
    }
{
 print cdatefile1
}' file1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming GNU `ls`, you want the `--time-style` option:

```
$ touch afile
$ ls -l afile
-rw-r--r-- 1 jackman jackman 0 Apr  2 08:54 afile
$ ls -l --time-style='+%m%d %H:%M' afile
-rw-r--r-- 1 jackman jackman 0 0402 08:54 afile
```

Comment: If you set `export LC_TIME=POSIX`, then default time format is: `"+%b %e %H:%M"` for files less than 6 months old, `"+%b %e  %Y"` otherwise.